# Instanciar classe dentro do arquivo bootstrap/start.php Laravel 4.2?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent, laravel-4

Tenho uma aplicação rodando `Laravel 4.2`, tenho uma classe que cuida de `IP's` numa `blacklist`, e esta esta está salva no banco.

Preciso que quando um usuário acesse minha aplicação o sistema valida se o `IP` está na `blacklist` retorna um **403**, se não deixa acessar. Estou tentando instanciar a classe `BlackListIpController` dentro do arquivo `bootstrap/start.php` (*arquivo que inicia a aplicação*) porém, sem exito.

#### Código:

```
$model = new app\controllers\BlackListIPsController;
if($model::where('ip', $model->getIp())->first()) {
    abort(403);
}
```

#### Erro:

> [Fri Jun  9 09:19:18 2017] PHP Fatal error:  Undefined constant
>   'app\controllers\BlackListIPsController' in
>   /home/user/projetos/abc/bootstrap/start.php on line 16
>
> [Fri Jun  9 09:36:53 2017] PHP Fatal error:  Class
>   'app\controllers\BlackListIPsController' not found in
>   /home/user/projetos/abc/bootstrap/start.php on line 16

Comment: Se tem que criar um filter no caso de Laravel

Comment: Ah legal, pode me dar uma ajuda de como eu faço isso ?

Comment: Você pode criar um middleware para tratar isso.

Comment: @KayoBruno não tem middleware no 4.2 é filter!

Comment: @DaniloTiagoThaiSantos fiz um exemplo ... !!!

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Vlws por avisar mano, não sabia disso. Só trabalhei com laravel 5.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize a técnica que é feita para isso que é [Route Filters - Documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters), exemplo:

Abra o arquivo `app\filters.php` e crie um `filter` de nome `ipblock`:

```
Route::filter('ipblock', function()
{
    // aqui você coloca a sua lógica se não passar só fiz uma 
    // cópia do que está na sua pergunta acho eu que está ainda
    // errado, mas, só corrigir a sua lógica.
    $model = new app\controllers\BlackListIPsController;
    if($model->where('ip', $model->getIp())->first()) {
        abort(403);
    }
});
```

depois de criado esse `filter` você deve entrar no `app\routes.php` e crie um [Route::group](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-groups) com esse filtro, exemplo:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'ipblock'), function()
{
     // insira as rotas que seram verificadas e protegidas por
     // esse filtro, exemplo
     Route::get( ....

});
```

ou se quiser individualmente:

```
Route::get('user', array('before' => 'ipblock', function()
{
    return '...';
}));
```

pronto se ele não passar no filtro ele da ***403*** igual você deseja.

***Observação:***

[Para pegar o ip veja link](https://laravel.io/forum/07-27-2014-get-ip-client-laravel-4), exemplo:

```
Request::getClientIp();
```

---

Existe também uma maneira de trabalhar com os eventos da sua aplicação ou filtros da aplicação que é pelos comandos (no seu caso é `App::before`, mas, adicionado os outros como exemplo):

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    //coloque a lógica aqui
});
```

---

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    //coloque a lógica aqui
});
```

---

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception)
{
   //coloque a lógica aqui
});
```

que estão localizados também no `app\filters.php`.

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Route Filters](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters)
- [Route Groups](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-groups)
- [Application Events](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/lifecycle#application-events)
- [Registering a Before Application Filter](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/53/registering-a-before-application-filter)

Comment: Cara perfeito ! vou usar esse, só uma dúvida: tu criou em cima de rotas específicas, caso eu  queira que seja pra toda aplicação, por exemplo, logo que ele acessar meu domínio (momento que a aplicação é instanciada) eu já quero fazer a verificação de IP. Então pra mim na verdade não importa a rota, do jeito que está montado eu terei que colocar um grupo de rotas com o novo filtro e todas as rotas da minha aplicação ficarem dentro dela... No caso, eu preciso que logo quando a aplicação for instanciada o sistema fazer essa verificação independente da rota .. será que consigo fazer isso ?

Comment: @DaniloTiagoThaiSantos sim fiz a edição é a última parte da resposta ..., mas, ainda se for dar uma opinião colocar isso nas rotas mesmo ... mas, claro existe sim a opção ...

Comment: Cara, parabéns, perfeito ! muito obrigado mesmo !!!!